# How to return a string for rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, scope

Use method in helper to hide or show a link accordingly. The method new_cate? works as designed. However the method link_to_edit? causes the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `cate' for #<#<Class:0x4ed6a10>:0x4ed2d38>

Extracted source (around line #23):

20:   <tr>
21:     <td><%= cate.name %></td>
22:     <td><%= cate.description %></td>
23:     <td><%= link_to_edit? %>></td>
24: 
25:   </tr>
26: <% end %>
```

Here is the code:

in index.html.erb

```
<body>

<h2>Category</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Description</th>

  </tr>

<% @categories.each do |cate| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= cate.name %></td>
    <td><%= cate.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to_edit? %>></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

  <%= new_cate? %>

</body>
```

in categories_helper.rb

```
  def new_cate?
    if session[:eng_dh] 
      return link_to 'New Category', new_category_path
    end
  end

  def link_to_edit?
    if session[:eng_dh]
      return link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(cate)
    end
  end
```

The code following "return" seems weird. new_cate? works as designed. But link_to_edit? does not.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to a method scope variable (which is not yet declared in that scope).

I guess what you want is

```
#in controller
def link_to_edit cate
if session[:eng_dh]
  return link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(cate)
end
```

end

```
#in view
<% @categories.each do |cate| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= cate.name %></td>
    <td><%= cate.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to_edit cate %>></td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tried The following : return link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(@cate) and have the error:No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"categories"}. Tried to use |@cate| in index.html.erb and received the error: formal argument cannot be an instance variable'); @categories.each do |@cate|.  The purpose of the helper method is to hide/show the edit link according to user's access right.

Comment: Rails does not like to use if in view file. That's why the if was moved into the helper file

Comment: Just accepted the answer. BTW What's the stuff returned by the method? Is it a html element for rails view?

Comment: It returns a string of HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in your link_to_edit function.

In your view pass the variable cate.

```
<td><%= link_to_edit(cate) %></td>
```

and in the controller

```
  def link_to_edit(cate)
    if session[:eng_dh]
      return link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(cate)
    end
  end
```